# Iterate bug in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator

When I add inn an iterator into my model, the first tool (which in this case is "make XY event layer") keeps running in a loop. This occurs even if the iterator is not even connected to anything. Once I remove the iterator it seems to work as normal.

Any idea why?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is how the Iterator works. It iterates the entire model for all the processes inside.

If you only want to run Make XY Event Layer once, you'll need to do a model-in-a-model.

Put the Make XY and any other pieces you only want run once into their own model. Then bring the iterator model into this run-once model. You'll probably need to use Collect Values in your case based on what I see.

Comment: Yeah I know it is supposed to rerun but not before the model has reached "split by attribute" and stored the tables in the folder. After that has finished I expected the iterator to cycle through the rest of the model using those newly created tables?

Comment: No, it doesn't work like that. There is no notion that part of the model is "behind" the iterator, thus it only runs once.

Comment: You could try to add a precondition to have something run first and control execution order (not sure if it'll work with the iterator), but all components will be run multiple times.

Comment: I tested this using a precondition and it did not work.  You have to do a model in model, as KHibma said.  Otherwise it will keep running the split tool, and you will never get to the end.

Comment: Ah okay, I did not know that. Thank you!